# Javascript: How to get key of function.apply()

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to cache 'func.apply(this, func)' value so that it can be looked up later rather than running the function again. The problem is that I don't know how or what to use as the key.

Is there a way to assign an key of a function that can be looked up later?

Code example:

```
var m = function(func) {
  var cached = {};
  return function() {
    var key = ''; // how do I get or create the key of func.apply(this, func)?

    if (cached[key]) {
      return cached[key];
    }

    cached[key] = func.apply(this, arguments);
    return cached[key];
  };

};
```

The m() function should return a function that, when called, will check if it has already computed the result for the given argument and return that value instead if possible.

Comment: what do you mean by `index`

Comment: The way you have it set up every time you would call it you would blow away the cache.

Comment: @ArunPJohny maybe I am not asking the same thing. How do I cache func.apply(this, func) and look it up later?

Comment: @nolabel how do we know whether it was the same call, it will depend upon `this` and the `func` value

Comment: I'm pretty sure you meant `func.apply(this, arguments)` not `func.apply(this, func)`?

Comment: @Bergi you are correct! Or I think you are.

Comment: What to choose as an index depends on `func` and how it uses its parameters, but usually you'd want to serialise `arguments` to a map key somehow (e.g. `JSON.stringify`).

Comment: Your `cached` variable is in the wrong scope FYI... Also FYI -- this is a bad idea. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @JonathanGray It is a simple way to not run an expensive calculation if it has already been done.

Comment: @epascarello There are much better ways of caching results (none of which would try to be a one-size-fits-all solution).

Comment: @JonathanGray That is personal opinion... :)

Comment: @epascarello Maybe, but it's an informed opinion

Comment: I already have the best algorithm for doing this in my head (it actually can be done without worrying about possible glitches). But I won't take the time to answer this question without proper justification. Any algorithm to do it properly will be inefficient at best.

Comment: @JonathanGray: Now you've made us curious what you consider "best" :-) And can you reason about why such an algorithm will be inefficient if done properly?

Comment: Someone needs a snickers. A generic solution will always have glitches. If you know exactly what you have, you can build a solid solution.

Comment: @Bergi The best way to do it would be to have the cache be a multi-dimensional array (an array of arrays). The sub-arrays will contain [this,arg1,arg2...]. These arrays would have the results in a key called `result`. When calling the method it will need to iterate over the cache to find matches in arguments and if found, return the associated result. If not, run the method, store and return the result. It's not nearly efficient as one would hope it would be but it's the only way to do it correctly.

Comment: @JonathanGray: I'm not sure what exactly your demands on correctness are, but I'd guess a structure of nested [`Map`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) (or even `WeakMap`s) could do better.

Comment: @Bergi Well, I never knew about that but if you can use anything as a key that seems like the perfect solution. In which case you've successfully changed my mind. But this leaves me to wonder... Where's your answer? Surely that has to be the best solution.

Comment: I still think whatever the case that this is a bad idea. But to each their own.

Comment: @JonathanGray: It's not a bad idea, it's just (like many optimisations) trading time for memory. It might not be applicable when it's little time traded for much memory of course, but there are reasonable use cases for it. And whether you'd use `Map`s or not depends a lot on whether you want to compare objects (in the arguments) by identity or by value (which leads down a whole other rabbit holes), and whether you expect objects at all.

Comment: @Bergi I believe the whole point of this is for universal application. Otherwise it's absolutely pointless (it's nothing more than trivial to cache specific results on a per-method/scenario basis)

Comment: @JonathanGray: OK, I agree that *that* is a bad idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for is called [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

See: [Implementing Memoization in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-memoization-in-javascript/)

Here are an example:

```
var myFunction = (function() {
  'use strict';

  var functionMemoized = function() {
    // set the argumensts list as a json key
    var cacheKey = JSON.stringify(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    var result;

    // checks whether the property was cached previously
    // also: if (!(cacheKey in functionMemoized.cache))
    if (!functionMemoized.cache.hasOwnProperty(cacheKey)) {
        // your expensive computation goes here
        // to reference the paramaters passed, use arguments[n]
        // eg.: result = arguments[0] * arguments[1];
        functionMemoized.cache[cacheKey] = result;
    }

    return functionMemoized.cache[cacheKey];
  };

  functionMemoized.cache = {};

  return functionMemoized;
}());
```

Comment: Your implementation has one flaw. If the calculation returns a falsey value it will always run the calculation.

Comment: Care to explain "Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)"?

Comment: @epascarello: +1 you are right, I will change it to test for `undefined`, or using `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @nolabel, `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` convert a _like-array_ `arguments` object, to a real `Array`

Comment: What if the arguments include objects that can't be converted easily using `JSON.stringify`? For example an HTML element. Other things that could break this would include using a native function as a parameter. Or a method being called with a bound callback.

Comment: @jherax can an Array be used as a key?

Comment: @nolabel Only strings can be used as keys. An object/array will be converted to a string if used directly.

Comment: @JonathanGray I understand your point, it is good, but I omit functions because a function defines a behavior, which always can change, thus there are a few reasons to keep cache of a behavior which is not consistent. That is why [JSON](http://json.org/) format not allows behaviors.

Comment: @nolabel, In JavaScript, property names in an object is always a string, that is why I used JSON format, in order to create the key of the cache object. See http://json.org/

Comment: @jherax thanks! I'm more interested in the how/why rather than the solution itself. I'm just trying to understand it rather than copying and pasting a solution.

Comment: @nolabel, That is the right way, trying to understand the code, make questions is much important than copy/paste code, that's why I like post references in my answers, in this case, the concept of **Memoization**. I encourage you to read the article posted :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need an object with an index. Just store the result/key.

```
var m = function(func) {
    var result=null;
    return function() {
        if (result===null) {
            result = func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

But I am not sure that is what you want. If the function returns different values based on arguments, than you want to use a key based off the arguments.

```js
var m = function(func) {
        var results = {};
        return function() {
            var key = [].slice.call(arguments).join("-");
            if (results[key]===undefined) {
                results[key] = func.apply(this, arguments);
            }
            return results[key];
        }
    };


    var multiply = function (a,b) {
        return a * b;  
    }
    var mult = m(multiply);
    console.log(mult(2,5));  //runs calculation
    console.log(mult(2,5));  //uses cache
```

Comment: I guess the actual question is whether `[].slice.call(arguments).join("-")` is a good index (key) for your map of cached results.

Comment: By index I think he means key. So his question really is what to use as a key

Comment: The best key really depends on what the arguments actually contain. Multiple ways to make a key, I just joined it with a random character. It could be a comma, space, phrase, etc

Comment: @epascarello: You should put that comment in your answer. And notice that joining on an arbitrary delimiter without escaping any values is only going to work when the input is limited. Also this implies that the arguments only consist of strings.

Answer (score -1):

If you send the value of the function as a string, you can use that as the index with one minor modification

```
var m = function(func, scope) {

  return function() {
    var cached = {};
    var index = func; // how do I get or create the index of func.apply(this, func)?
    scope = scope || this;
    if (!cached[index]) {
        func = scope[func]; //Get the reference to the function through the name
        cached[index] = func.apply(this, func);          
    }

    return cached[index];
  };

};
```

This does depend on if the index exists in the `this` object reference.  Otherwise you should use a different scope.

Comment: What I had in mind, but this failed, e.g., m(function(a,b) { return a + b; });

Comment: Where are you defining the function you are trying to call? Is it global?

Comment: Using `func` as the lookup key makes no sense at all.